# How to properly configure the application in electron for compatibility with windows 7, through the command prompt?

Tags: cmd, configuration, electron, compatibility

I am creating an application in electron, but I can only send notifications if the application is in compatibility mode with windowns 7

I found a way to perform compatibility mode configuration through the command prompt (`REG.EXE ADD "HKLM \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows NT \ CurrentVersion \ AppCompatFlags \ Layers" / v "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Application \ Application.EXE "/ t REG_SZ / d" WIN7RTM "/ f)`,

however this setting is not working the same way when manually configuring compatibility mode.

When I perform compatibility mode configuration through properties / compatibility / compatibility mode and change to windows 7, the notifications work perfectly, however with the command `REG.EXE ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Aplication\Aplication.exe" /t REG_SZ /d "WIN7RTM" /f` The application does not behave in the same way, although it is observed in the properties, the mode is apparently configured the same way.

I need to know if there is a need to put any more information on my command, or if I happen to be doing it totally wrong. Would you help me?